# To shrink a string "abbcccbfgh" by removing conescutive k characters till no removal can be done

Tags: java, logic

To shrink a string "abbcccbfgh" by removing consecutive k characters till no removal can be done.
e.g. for k=3 output for the above string will be "afgh".
Please note that K and string both are dynamic i.e provided by the user.

I wrote the below program but I couldn't complete it. Please help.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "abbcccbfgh";
        int k = 3;

        String result = removeConsecutive(str, k);
        System.out.print("result is " + result);
    }

    private static String removeConsecutive(String str, int k) {
        String str1 = str + "";
        String res = "";
        int len = str.length();
        char c1 = 0, c2 = 0;
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
            c1 = str.charAt(i);
            c2 = str.charAt(i + 1);

            if (c1 == c2) {
                count++;
            } else {

                res = res + String.valueOf(c1);
                count = 0;
            }
            if (count == k-1) {
                //remove String

            }
        }

        return res;
    }
```

Comment: Why would "abbcccbfgh" result in "afgh"? Why would the 2 bs be removed altogether, but not the other chars?

Comment: First of all, when you are appending to strings, it is good practice to use `StringBuilder`s and not just `String`s as `String`s are immutable.
As for your question, try using a stack that stores the character and its current count.

Comment: I assume `b` and `c` are deleted because the count of its characters in the string is equal to `k`? Then how about creating two loop. The first loop counts all of the characters occurrence in the string (save the count of each character in a new array). The second loop returns the string whose character count is not equal with `k` (Using the array we created earlier).

Comment: @daniu I believe "abbcccbfgh" becomes "abb bfgh" after k=3 consecutive Cs are removed. And that results in "abbbfgh" becoming "afgh".

Comment: @Vj- makes sense, I forgot to apply the "consecutive" rules..

Comment: Can someone please tell me how to write a code for this!

Comment: hint: use a stack

Comment: is it okey to have recursion ?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to do it with regex:

```
    int l = 0;
    do {
        l = str.length();
        str = str.replaceAll("(.)\\1{" + n + "}", "");
    } while (l != str.length());
```

n = k - 1

(.)\1{2} means any character followed by n same characters. \1 means the same character as in group #1

Comment: Can you suggest me a way of doing it without regex

Answer (score 0):

Is it okey to have recursion ?

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "abbcccbfgh";
        int k = 3;

        String result = removeConsecutive(str, k);
        System.out.print("result is " + result);
    }

    private static String removeConsecutive(String str, int k) {

        String ret = str;
        int len = str.length();

        int count = 0;
        char c1 = 0 ;
        char c2 = 0;
        char last = 0 ;

        for (int i = 0; i < ret.length()-1; i++) {
            last = c1 ;
            c1 = str.charAt(i);
            c2 = str.charAt(i + 1);

            if (c1 == c2 ) {
                if( count > 0 ) {
                    if( last == c1 ) {
                        count ++ ;
                    }
                    else {
                        count = 0;
                    }
                }
                else {
                count++;
                }
            } else {
                count = 0;
            }


            if (count == k-1) {


                int start = ((i+1) - k) + 1 ;

                String one = str.substring(0, start) ;
                String two = str.substring(start+k);

                String new1 = one + two ;
                //recursion
                ret = removeConsecutive(new1, k) ;
                count = 0;

            }
        }

        return ret;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a stack. For each character `ch` in the string, push it to the stack, if there's 3 consecutive same characters, pop them all. In the end, convert the stack to a string. You can improve the program a little by using a special stack that remembers the number of occurrences of each element.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class Reduce implements Function<String, String> {
    private final int k;

    public Reduce(final int k) {
        if (k <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        this.k = k;
    }

    @Override
    public String apply(final String s) {
        Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();
        for (Character ch : s.toCharArray()) {
            stack.push(ch);
            if (stack.topCount() == k) {
                stack.pop();
            }
        }
        return stack.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Reduce reduce = new Reduce(3);
        System.out.println(reduce.apply("abbcccbfgh"));
    }

    private static class Stack<T> {
        private class Node {
            private T value;
            private int count;

            Node(T value) {
                this.value = value;
                this.count = 1;
            }
        }
        private List<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<>();

        public void push(T value) {
            if (nodes.isEmpty() || !top().value.equals(value)) {
                nodes.add(new Node(value));
            } else {
                top().count++;
            }
        }

        public int topCount() {
            return top().count;
        }

        public void pop() {
            nodes.remove(nodes.size()-1);
        }

        private Node top() {
            return nodes.get(nodes.size()-1);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            nodes.forEach(n->{
                for (int i = 0; i < n.count; i++) {
                    sb.append(n.value);
                }
            });
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }
}
```